# netboot installation "pkgsel" failed

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, pxe, preseed, debian-installer

I am trying to do a pxe installation and after the base system getting installed, the installer fails at the menu item "Select & Install Software":

[image: Screenshot -Where it got stuck]

On looking at the logs using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>. I could see the below error show in the screenshot attached:

[image: Screenshot - Logs]